# Open URL Within App in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, safari

In my application I want a URL to be open within the app not in safari, Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIWebView is your answer if you want to load a webpage inside of your app.

```
// example:

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
[[self view] addSubview:webView];
```

If you really want to get fancy, you can use your own UIApplication subclass and intercept the OpenURL method in your application and then pop up a modal view or something along those lines to open the URL in your app, when it normally would have opened the URL outside of your app.